# Questions Copied from Math StackExchange and placed on other Websites

Tags: support, scraper-sites

I have posted a question on Math.SE and spent a lot of time improving it as it has been on hold.

However an earlier inferior version of my question has appeared on a website called queryxchange.com. I am not going to post a link this must be happening to others as well.

I have never signed in to such a website and my name on the website is not a link to a user login page, but is just a link to the ripped off web page itself. Therefore the web page has not been created by a user claiming my identity, but is a copy created directly by the operators of the website.

I assume that math.SE does not condone this practice, which appears to me to be blatant copyright infringement. What can be done to stop this website ripping questions from Math.SE without the users permission?

Comment: [This one](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23557/is-selling-a-compilation-of-math-stackexchange-qas-legal) more or less answered your question.

Comment: @JohnMa: Thanks. There is a difference however between a website writing such and such posted this on Math.SE and quoting text plus a link to Math.SE, and a website spoofing users names and content to make it appear that the same user is posting the same or similar questions on different websites.

Comment: If you find a site that appears to be copying content without attribution, there is a report web form one can use on the stack exchange main site to report it. Clearing up such disputes is a long process, and we might not see results soon. And maybe someone has already reported that one.

Comment: @user296602: Thanks I've now reported the offending site. To add insult to injury they add their own copyright claim at the bottom of the page "Copyright © QueryXchange 2017" What a cheek.

Comment: While the [Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license affords some legitimate use of StackExchange content, the site you mention does not observe the proper attribution to original authors and is thus is not legitimate.  The usual term for these is "scraper site".